# Java ProcessBuilder: How to suppress output instead of redirecting it

Tags: java, java-8

I'm using a ProcessBuilder to execute commands and redirect the output. I now want to add the possibility to have no output at all.

Of course I could redirect into a file, but this would leave unnecessary files on the users system.

I am looking for a solution that

- works on all platforms, including Windows (e.g. not redirecting to /dev/null)
- does not misuse try-catch (e.g. redirecting to null and ignore the exception)

The only way I could find was this:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
if (suppressOutput) {
        processBuilder.redirectOutput(ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT);
}
```

But that prints to the underlying shell, which is not literally "no output".

Here is my use of processBuilder with output not surpressed:

```
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
processBuilder.directory(new File(workingdir));
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process = processBuilder.start();

while (process.isAlive()) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { }
    // check for termination request
    if (terminationRequest()) {
        process.destroy();
        return -1;
    }
}
return process.exitValue();
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `DISCARD` redirect option has been added in Java 9. You could use that if you upgrade Java. Otherwise, you could simply replicate that behaviour because the `DISCARD` redirect enum uses a file instance which redirects to null device as below.

```
   private static File NULL_FILE = new File(
          (System.getProperty("os.name")
                     .startsWith("Windows") ? "NUL" : "/dev/null")
   );
```

Then you could use the overloaded `redirectOutput` method;

```
if (suppressOutput) {
   processBuilder.redirectOutput(NULL_FILE);
}
```

This is identical to Java 9's behaviour.

Comment: Are you reusing the processbuilder instance?

Comment: Have you tried running your code on the terminal (not on Eclipse)? Also post the full working example, so I may be able to try.

Comment: It's working. Sorry for the confusion. I had some side effects from other code that effects my logging service.

Answer (score 2):

The Java 9+ solution for discarding the output of the Process:

```java
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
processBuilder.redirectOutput(Redirect.DISCARD);
processBuilder.redirectError(Redirect.DISCARD);
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```